# uninitialized constant sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

New rails project.

Rails 5.0.2
Sidekiq 4.2.10

I ran `rails g sidekiq:worker deposit_collector` and then filled out the code I needed inside the `perform` method.

To test I logged into the rails console and typed: `DepositCollector.perform_async` and I get the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DepositCollectorWorker
```

The worker is where it should be in the `app/workers/` folder. I've used sidekiq on several projects before and have never run into this.

Comment: I ran into an issue and it was because rails wanted the worker file to end in `worker.rb`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default, Rails will include all subdirectories of the `app` folder in the [autoload paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) list.  You can review the list of autoload paths in the console with:

```
puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
```

But Rails only looks for these paths at boot time.  So when you add a new folder, like `app/workers`, it is not enough to restart the Rails console.  You need to both exit the Rails console and stop the [Spring Application Preloader](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#spring-application-preloader) with:

```
spring stop
```

Then start up the Rails console again and the files in the `app/workers` folder will load properly.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have spring installed so I took the lazy approach and turned on eager loading in my *config/environments/development.rb* file:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

and then turned it back to false after restarting my server.